# heapq nsmallest dictionary key sorted

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have an innested dictionary, for example

```
>>> d={
    'out_key': {'aa1':2, 'aa2':3, 'a1':5, 'aa0':2, 'b':1}
}
```

From this dict I want the first `n` keys with smallest value. In order to do this I know I can use `heap.nsmallest` in this way:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> smallest_2 = heapq.nsmallest(2,d['out_key'],key=d['out_key'].get)
>>> smallest_2
['b', 'aa1']
```

However in the `key` I would like to add one more condition, namely to have the keys sorted. So that `smallest_2=['b', 'aa0]`. (Notice `smallest_2` is not required to be sorted.)

My first (failed) attempt was to set `key=f` where

```
f = lambda x: sorted(x['out_key].get)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first (failed) attempt, you were thinking about it wrongly, you should use use both value as well as key for `key` argument of `heapq.nsmallest()` . Example -

```
>>> d={
...     'out_key': {'aa1':2, 'aa2':3, 'a1':5, 'aa0':2, 'b':1}
... }
>>>
>>> import heapq
>>> >>> heapq.nsmallest(2,d['out_key'],key=lambda x: (d['out_key'].get(x),x))
['b', 'aa0']
```

Comment: @rafforaffo Glad I could be helpful! :-) . Just  FYI , a better way would be to use both value as well as key in `key` argument , as updated above (would be faster than sorting keys) .

Comment: is it better in terms of time, i.e. avoiding `sorted()` saves computation?

Comment: @rafforaffo yes, it should be faster than `sorted()` , since `sorted()` would first sort the complete list of keys, and then use the heapq logic on it, whereas using the `key` argument` avoids that.